# Append li with a link that has a custom click event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a li element to a list with a link that has custom click event... I am trying something like:

```
<div id="myid"><ul></ul></div>

$('#myid ul').append("<li><a href=''>Link</a></li>").click(function(){alert('hi')})
```

But the click event is on the **li** and not the **a href**.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the click event handler is bound to the `ul` element.

> How do I fix this?

Bind it to the `a` element:

```
$("<li><a href=''>Link</a></li>").find('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- if you don't want the browser follow the link
    alert('hi');
}).end().appendTo('#myid ul');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/X6KSG/)

Creating the link separately might be cleaner though:

```
$('<a />', {
    text: "Link",
    href: "",
    click: function() {/*...*/}
}).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo('#myid ul');
```

Information about the methods used can be found in the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Really elegant and jQuerish solution!

Comment: That is awesome... thanks for the bit on the preventDefault()... I didn't know that existed!

Comment: Love the 2nd example, although shouldn't there be a .parent() after the wrap and before the appendTo? I realise this is now 3 years old so jQuery may have changed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.on` since your li is being appended on the fly

```
 $('#myid ul').append('<li id="li1"><a href=''>Link</a></li>');

    $('body').on('click','#li1',function(){
         alert('hi');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myid ul').append("<li><a href=''>Link</a></li>");

$("a").live("click", function() { // or use on(...)
    alert('hi');
});
```

Bind the click, on live, to the a element after appending. Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/reygonzales/Z5pSC/

Comment: Don't use live. It's deprecated

Comment: Yea, on() is better because its supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myid ul').append("<li><a href=''>Link</a></li>")
     .find("a:last").click(function(){
         alert('hi')
})​​​​;
```